# Bulge in the center of a bit of text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I'd like to create a bulge in a section of text that makes it looks like a sphere is pushing through. The below image is kind of what I'm going for. I would really appreciate any help on this.

[image: sphere bulge text]

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like a simple enough effect to do with the standard illustrator filters.

Comment: Luciano, I am a relative novice when it comes to Illustrator. I've tried playing around with the Envelope Distort and Warp functions but haven't managed to get the effect right. I can warp or distort the entire text to the sphere no problem but it's getting the single spot in the section of text warped that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1 . . . Non-Destructive

- Set your lines of text
- Select all the text as an object using the **Selection Tool**
- Choose **`Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh`** from the menu
- Enter **2 Rows** and **2 Columns** for the Mesh options
- Select **only** the center anchor point of the mesh, and click `OK`
- **Double-click** the **Scale Tool** in the **Toolbar** and enter a value *greater* than 100% in the `Uniform` field (tick `Preview` to see it change.)

[image]

This leaves the text **live**. So if you need to then edit the text, simply select the object with the **Selection Tool** and choose **`Object > Envelope Distort > Edit Contents`** and you can change the text.

---

## Option 2 . . .  Destructive

This method is more of a "trial and error" method. Often it takes a few attempt to get something you like. This isn't as precise as using the envelope and scale option.

- Set the text
- Use **`Type > Create Outlines`** to, well, create outlines of the text
- Select the **Bloat Tool**
- Double-click the **Bloat Tool** in the **Toolbar** to adjust its' options. *You may need to do this a couple times until you get the hang of what the options are doing.*
- Click on the text. *Again, you may need to `Undo` and then try again a few times to get what you are after.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't add pictures now so i'll try to describe in words:

1. Turn the text to outlines.
2. Draw a square in the size of part that you want to bulge.
3. Select text and square and use "divide" in the pathfinder window.
4. Then select everything within the Square and use the FishEye warp
   effect on that.